# How do you view corrgrapher object in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to show a `corrgrapher` object within Shiny, which allows a user to move the nodes. The package help says  *"Feel free to pass it into plot, include it in knitr report or generate a simple HTML."* but I am struggling with the right syntax. What am I missing?

**Object looks like this**:

[image: Corrgrapher relationships]

**Code**

See example below. I tried HTMLOutput/renderHTML as well.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(corrgrapher)

if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    
    fluidRow(h1("corrgrapher plot"),
             plotOutput("corrgram"))
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$corrgram <- renderPlot({
      plotdata <- corrgrapher(mtcars)  
      plot(plotdata)
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way given in your answer works but it is better to use the **visNetwork** package. Indeed, `plot(corrgrapher(data))` returns a `visNetwork` object and then you can use some options. You can also use the `visNetworkProxy` to do a lot of things.

```r
library(shiny)
library(corrgrapher)
library(visNetwork)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
    h1("corrgrapher plot"),
    visNetworkOutput("corrgram")
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$corrgram <- renderVisNetwork({
    cg <- corrgrapher(mtcars)  
    plot(cg) |> visOptions(nodesIdSelection = TRUE)
  })
  
  observe({
    print(input$corrgram_selected)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops figured it out:

```
if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    
    fluidRow(h1("corrgrapher plot"),
             uiOutput("corrgram"))
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$corrgram <- renderUI({
      
      plot(corrgrapher(mtcars))

    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```